# Storyboard - No completed event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, animation, storyboard

This is probably a simple question, but how do I know when a Storyboard animation has completed? I'm using .Net 3.0 so maybe that's why, but in my other projects (.net 4), there was a simple Completed event I could handle. What's the way to do it in WPF with .net 3.0?
Thanks

edit in response to comments: 
I guess the error lies elsewhere. I can't access my storyboard from the code-behind.

```
//storyboardBounce does not exist error is thrown
  storyboardBounce.Completed += new EventHandler(Storyboard_Completed);
```

However, if I assign triggers to buttons in Blend, I can access them like this:

```
 sbDisplayContents_BeginStoryboard.Storyboard.Completed += new EventHandler(Storyboard_Completed);
```

But since there are many triggers calling the same storyboard, I would have to manually set the event handlers for each one like the above. Is there a reason my storyboard can't be accessed from the code-behind? Or is there a way to have multiple triggers assigned to the same storyboard so that I don't have to handle the Completed event for

> ```
>  sbDisplayContents_BeginStoryboard...
>  sbDisplayContents_BeginStoryboard1...
>  sbDisplayContents_BeginStoryboard2...
> ```

etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Completed` event exists in 3.0... (it's inherited from `Timeline`)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx

> Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0

---

UPDATE

If your storyboard is declared in the resources, you can't access it directly in code-behind. You need to call `FindResource` :

```
StoryBoard storyboardBounce = FindResource("storyboardBounce") as StoryBoard;
```

Comment: Thanks.I guess the error is elsewhere - I've updated my original post.